# c++ vector insert begin

Tags: c++, vector

I don't Know how to use the insert method of vectors, I have a problem with this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main () {

std::vector<int> v1(3);
std::vector<int> v2(3);

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    v1[i] = i + 1;

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    v2[i] = i + 4;

for(int i = 2; i <= 0; i--)
    v1.insert(v1.begin(), v2[i]);

for(int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++)
    std::cout << v1[i] << std::endl;

return 0;

}
```

why I have as video output 1 2 3 and not 4 5 1 2 3?

Comment: `for(int i = 2; i <= 0; i--)` aka NOP

Comment: @ssuljic: `vector` doesn't have `push_front()`.

Comment: Well, I don't know much about vectors... does the method push_front exist?

Comment: @John3136: You should make that an answer.

Comment: @John3136 thank you, i'm stupid!

Comment: @Wellen: No, you made a mistake. We all do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in the loop

```
for(int i = 2; i <= 0; i--)
    v1.insert(v1.begin(), v2[i]);
```

is incorrect. So the loop is skipped. I think you meant

```
for(int i = 2; i >= 0; i--)
    v1.insert(v1.begin(), v2[i]);
```